VScode is not selecting the highest version of python installed in linux
I'm on Linux (Fedora) and facing this issue, my vs-code is not selecting the latest python version 3.12, and keep on pointing python 3.11.
After spending an hour on google, below is what I did in my /bin directory. But still no luck. I tried taking help from chatGPT and it suggests to use: ln -s /bin/python3.12 python3.12 to create symbolic link. But where and how, neither me nor chatGPT was having clue (or may be I didn't ask nicely or I don't have much experience in Linux). How can I make vs-code to use 3.12 instead 3.11?
After clicking ctrl + shift + P I selected python.defaultInterpreterPath setting and pointed it towards /bin/python3.12, but :(.
any suggestion please? Thank you :)
HERE IS THE OUTPUT FROM /bin
user_name@user:~$ cd /bin
user_name@user:/bin$ 
user_name@user:/bin$ ls -lh | grep python
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root      16K Feb 19 05:30 abrt-action-analyze-python
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     5.3K Apr 15 05:30 activate-global-python-argcomplete
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root        9 Apr 17 05:30 python -> ./python3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       10 Apr 17 05:30 python3 -> python3.12
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root      16K Apr 17 05:30 python3.12
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     2.6K Apr 15 05:30 python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     2.0K Apr 15 05:30 register-python-argcomplete
user_name@user:/bin$ chmod 777 python3.12
chmod: changing permissions of 'python3.12': Operation not permitted
user_name@user:/bin$ sudo chmod 777 python3.12
[sudo] password for user_name: 
user_name@user:/bin$ 
user_name@user:/bin$ 
user_name@user:/bin$ ls -lh | grep python
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root      16K Feb 19 05:30 abrt-action-analyze-python
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     5.3K Apr 15 05:30 activate-global-python-argcomplete
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root        9 Apr 17 05:30 python -> ./python3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       10 Apr 17 05:30 python3 -> python3.12
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      16K Apr 17 05:30 python3.12
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     2.6K Apr 15 05:30 python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root     2.0K Apr 15 05:30 register-python-argcomplete
user_name@user:/bin$ 
user_name@user:/bin$

PYTHON INSTALLATION (ALL THREE). All were pre-installed.
user_name@user:~$ 
user_name@user:~$ which python
/usr/bin/python
user_name@user:~$ which python3.12
/usr/bin/python3.12
user_name@user:~$ 
user_name@user:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
user_name@user:~$ 
user_name@user:~$

HERE IS THE OUTPUT FROM /usr/bin
user_name@user:~$ 
user_name@user:~$ 
user_name@user:~$ cd /usr/bin
user_name@user:/usr/bin$ ls -ls | grep python
   16 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       16128 Feb 19 05:30 abrt-action-analyze-python
    8 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root        5352 Apr 15 05:30 activate-global-python-argcomplete
    4 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root           9 Apr 17 05:30 python -> ./python3
    4 lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root          10 Apr 17 05:30 python3 -> python3.12
   16 -rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       15976 Apr 17 05:30 python3.12
    4 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root        2610 Apr 15 05:30 python-argcomplete-check-easy-install-script
    4 -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root        1998 Apr 15 05:30 register-python-argcomplete
user_name@user:/usr/bin$ 



Screenshot #1 from vs-code
Screenshot #2 from vs-code
Here are the logs if I click on show output.
2024-06-02 19:16:50.510 [info] Experiment 'pythonaa' is active
2024-06-02 19:16:50.510 [info] Experiment 'pythonCreateEnvOnPipInstall' is active
2024-06-02 19:16:50.510 [info] Experiment 'pythonRecommendTensorboardExt' is active
2024-06-02 19:16:50.510 [info] Experiment 'pythonTerminalEnvVarActivation' is active
2024-06-02 19:16:50.510 [info] Experiment 'pythonTestAdapter' is active
2024-06-02 19:16:50.510 [info] Default formatter is set to null for workspace /home/user_name/Documents/Python_Projects
2024-06-02 19:16:50.510 [info] Python interpreter path: /bin/python
2024-06-02 19:16:50.608 [info] > pyenv which python
2024-06-02 19:16:50.608 [info] cwd: .
2024-06-02 19:16:51.182 [warning] Shell integration may not be active, environment activated may be overridden by the shell.
2024-06-02 19:16:51.493 [info] > conda info --json
2024-06-02 19:16:54.036 [info] Starting Pylance language server.
2024-06-02 19:16:56.372 [error] Unable to identify shell /bin/sh  for OS  Linux
2024-06-02 19:16:56.970 [info] Discover tests for workspace name: Python_Projects - uri: /home/user_name/Documents/Python_Projects/Learn/Python_Learn/sets.py
2024-06-02 19:16:57.229 [error] Unable to identify shell /bin/sh  for OS  Linux
2024-06-02 19:16:57.331 [info] Send text to terminal: /bin/python /home/user_name/Documents/Python_Projects/Learn/Python_Learn/sets.py
2024-06-02 19:17:38.481 [info] Discover tests for workspace name: undefined - uri: /home/user_name/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/config/Code/User/settings.json
2024-06-02 19:22:09.442 [info] > hatch env show --json
2024-06-02 19:22:09.442 [info] cwd: .
2024-06-02 19:22:09.460 [info] Found: /bin/python --> /usr/bin/python3.11
2024-06-02 19:22:09.462 [info] Found: /bin/python3 --> /bin/python3.11
2024-06-02 19:22:09.463 [info] Found: /bin/python3.11 --> /bin/python3.11
2024-06-02 19:22:09.500 [info] > /usr/bin/python3.12 -I ~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/get_output_via_markers.py ~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/interpreterInfo.py
2024-06-02 19:22:09.509 [info] Found: /sbin/python --> /usr/bin/python3.11
2024-06-02 19:22:09.510 [error] [Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python3.12 -I /home/user_name/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/get_output_via_markers.py /home/user_name/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/interpreterInfo.py
/bin/sh: line 1: /usr/bin/python3.12: No such file or directory

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:423:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:529:35)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:450:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:350:12)] {
  code: 127,
  killed: false,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/usr/bin/python3.12 -I /home/user_name/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/get_output_via_markers.py /home/user_name/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/interpreterInfo.py'
}
2024-06-02 19:22:09.511 [info] Found: /sbin/python3 --> /sbin/python3.11
2024-06-02 19:22:09.511 [info] Found: /sbin/python3.11 --> /sbin/python3.11
2024-06-02 19:22:09.517 [info] Found: /usr/bin/python --> /usr/bin/python3.11
2024-06-02 19:22:09.518 [info] Found: /usr/bin/python3 --> /usr/bin/python3.11
2024-06-02 19:22:09.518 [info] Found: /usr/bin/python3.11 --> /usr/bin/python3.11
2024-06-02 19:22:09.534 [info] Found: /usr/sbin/python --> /usr/bin/python3.11
2024-06-02 19:22:09.535 [info] Found: /usr/sbin/python3 --> /usr/sbin/python3.11
2024-06-02 19:22:09.535 [info] Found: /usr/sbin/python3.11 --> /usr/sbin/python3.11
2024-06-02 19:22:09.548 [info] > /bin/python -I ~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/get_output_via_markers.py ~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/interpreterInfo.py
2024-06-02 19:22:09.568 [info] > /bin/python3 -I ~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/get_output_via_markers.py ~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/interpreterInfo.py
2024-06-02 19:22:09.665 [info] > /sbin/python3 -I ~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/get_output_via_markers.py ~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/interpreterInfo.py
2024-06-02 19:22:09.681 [info] > /usr/sbin/python3 -I ~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/get_output_via_markers.py ~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/interpreterInfo.py
2024-06-02 19:22:11.533 [info] > /usr/bin/python3.12 -I ~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/get_output_via_markers.py ~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/interpreterInfo.py
2024-06-02 19:22:11.537 [error] [Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/python3.12 -I /home/user_name/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/get_output_via_markers.py /home/user_name/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/interpreterInfo.py
/bin/sh: line 1: /usr/bin/python3.12: No such file or directory

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:423:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:529:35)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:450:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:350:12)] {
  code: 127,
  killed: false,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/usr/bin/python3.12 -I /home/user_name/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/get_output_via_markers.py /home/user_name/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/interpreterInfo.py'
}
2024-06-02 19:23:22.773 [info] > /run/user/1000/doc/9b0b580a/python3.12 -I ~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/get_output_via_markers.py ~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/interpreterInfo.py
2024-06-02 19:23:22.777 [error] [Error: Command failed: /run/user/1000/doc/9b0b580a/python3.12 -I /home/user_name/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/get_output_via_markers.py /home/user_name/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/interpreterInfo.py
/run/user/1000/doc/9b0b580a/python3.12: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.12.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:423:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:529:35)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:303:5)] {
  code: 127,
  killed: false,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/run/user/1000/doc/9b0b580a/python3.12 -I /home/user_name/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/get_output_via_markers.py /home/user_name/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/interpreterInfo.py'
}
2024-06-02 19:23:24.782 [info] > /run/user/1000/doc/9b0b580a/python3.12 -I ~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/get_output_via_markers.py ~/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/interpreterInfo.py
2024-06-02 19:23:24.789 [error] [Error: Command failed: /run/user/1000/doc/9b0b580a/python3.12 -I /home/user_name/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/get_output_via_markers.py /home/user_name/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/interpreterInfo.py
/run/user/1000/doc/9b0b580a/python3.12: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.12.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:423:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:529:35)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:450:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:350:12)] {
  code: 127,
  killed: false,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/run/user/1000/doc/9b0b580a/python3.12 -I /home/user_name/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/get_output_via_markers.py /home/user_name/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2024.6.0/python_files/interpreterInfo.py'
}


chatGPT is not your friend. /bin is not the place you want to muck around. Start by typing which python in your shell, and go from there.

Thanks. Trust me I won't go in /bin after today. Will limit my scope till /home/user_name. I've updated outputs of which python in first post.

Please note that /bin is not the same as /usr/bin.  There is some stuff in bin but which says that python  is installed in /usr/bin

@Luuk Outputs updated from /usr/bin

try: Select and activate an environment

Does this answer your question? How can I change the Python version in Visual Studio Code?

@Pac0. Indeed I read that, but didn't solve my problem.

Check if Python 3.12 is executable and that you've already changed the permissions of the Python 3.12 interpreter to be executable for all users or not. This should be sufficient, but double-check by running:
/bin/python3.12 --version

If this returns Python 3.12, then the interpreter is correctly installed and executable.

It is, here is the response:
user_name@user:~$ /bin/python3.12 --version
Python 3.12.3
user_name@user:~$
